# Problem with http to https redirect

Tags: htaccess, https

I have the following .htaccess file (in `www.example.com/folder1/folder2`)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

to map any HTTP request in `folder2` to the corresponding HTTPS request.

This all works fine, but if I try to access

```
https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2
```

then I get to a

> "This web page is unavailable" ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error page.

But

```
http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2
https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/
```

both work fine (and end up displaying `https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/index.phtml` as expected)

I don't understand why the HTTPS version doesn't work when there is no / at the end of the URL.

Can anyone explain and provide a fix?

Comment: This behaviour is consistent with having `DirectorySlash Off` in your HTTPS VirtualHost. However, I would have expected a different error in this case, unless the error you are getting is related to the security cert?

Comment: Indeed, I wonder if the whole process of rewriting isn't adding the missing /. My understanding is rewriting will clean up URLs to make them valid.

Comment: Thanks both. I looked into DirectorySlash but that didn't help, and I also removed my rewrite code and that didn't help either! So I have bounced my query up to someone further up my organisation who deals with the root domain to ask them to investigate. Your comments, and my attempted changes based on them, convinced me that it almost certainly isn't my problem.